# Careers type of work selection

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, preferences

I edited my Job search/type of work selection of the profile, but after saving I still get:

> Job search status: actively looking . **You might also wish to indicate full-time vs part-time, telecommute, or willingness to relocate.**

The value is still there if I refresh and edit, but the same message persist. Is this normal? Should the type of work appear somewhere on the profile page?